# Iesi.Collections not loading?

Tags: nuget-package, iesi-collections

I want to use Nhibernate  and  I write a this code package console manager

Install-Package NHibernate

and I get this error

> Install-Package : Unable to resolve dependency 'Iesi.Collections (≥ 3.2.0.4000)'.
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  NHibernate
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

and then I want to install `Iesi.Collections` and i try  this code

```
PM> Install-Package Iesi.Collections -Version 3.2.0.4000
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Iesi.Collections'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Iesi.Collections -Version 3.2.0.4000
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Have any idea to solve this problem? :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exactly this problem this morning.

I'm guessing it was because different projects in my solution referenced different version of the same assemblies which made Nuget freak out.

I got it working after doing this:

1. Uninstall everything that depends on `Iesi.Collections` like `Nhibernate`, `FluentNHibernate` etc by running `Uninstall-Package <name>`.
2. Uninstall Iesi.Collections (`Uninstall-Package Iesi.Collections`)
3. (Verify that there isn't any references to different versions of the same assemblies, look in the packages-folder for multiple folders with different version number)
4. Add your nuget packages again

If you, like me, got quit a few packages and don't remember all of them on top of your head, Run `Get-Package` and copy output to notepad before you remove anything and you can simply add everything again in a minute.

(Edit: I'm running this version of Nuget http://nuget.codeplex.com/downloads/get/382255 after following some link in [this page](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1790))